# How to reduce the general size of Highchart

Tags: css, charts, highcharts

I want to display 4 chart in container like on this schema:
[image]

So I need to reduce the general size of the chart. I can't found anything to do something like chart.resize(totalsize/4) so it would reduce all the size.

Or maybe someone here as already displayed 4 charts like this but my goal is to display 3 containers each with 4 charts and responsive so if I reduce the window the containers goes one under one and the chart goes one under one too.

So for the moment my code is:

```
  <div class="tableChart">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">{{> chart chart_id=this.idChartMem}}</div>
              <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">{{> chart chart_id=this.idChartCPU}}</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">{{> chart chart_id=this.idChartNet}}</div>
              <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">{{> chart chart_id=this.idChartDisk}}</div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

And the result is:
[image]

That's why I need to reduce the general size of the charts

Comment: You can do it with bootstrap css. https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/

Comment: @al27091 I have already tried but I didn't reduce the size of the chart so it look like the edit in my question

Comment: If the chart is an image you can try with bootstrap class:  .img-responsive

Comment: No it's not an image is an Highchart

Comment: What about giving table the bootstrap class .table. Btw I think you do not even need a table if you use container, row and columns...

Comment: I don't really understand what you explained, can you show me an example ?

Comment: Wait look my edit now it's better !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should make a layout of two equal columns on a row and you can edit it 
adding more rows or more columns following bootstrap standard (https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/):

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      Your content here
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      Your content here
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So that you do not need a table to make a grid. And this can be made responsive adding style for smaller devices. For example:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
          Your content here
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
          Your content here
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This will make the column to fit all the available space in a extra small device (col-xs-12). Then you have also the col-sm-.. class for small device. You have only to choose what fit your needs.

Comment: Yes that's nice but now look the picture in my question, the chart are still too big. But this solution is the right one to display them like I wanted to !

Comment: I think you can work with media query and reduce the size by percentage for your highcart or try a smaller column.

Comment: With something like this: 
`@media (max-width: 500px) {
   .chartDiv {
      width: 25%;
      height: 25%;
   }
}`
?

Comment: I suppose so. Does it work? I also found this: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/responsive

Comment: With @media nothing has changed but the link your provided look really nice I'll work with that and give you a feedback

Comment: I can't make it works for me but I'll try with this, thank you for the help